# Use variable out of ajax

Tags: ajax, function

How I can use count variable out of ajax? In ajax function "count" shows count, but dessous nothing.

```
var count;
$.ajax({
cache   :   false,
dataType:   'json',
type    :   "POST",
url     :   "count.php",
success  :   function(tdata){
count = tdata;
console.log(count); //this works

}               

});

console.log(count); //this doesn't work
```

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work ? Does it say "undefined" ?

Comment: Your ajax call is asynchronous, so your console log getting print before response, you can make it sync but it is not good practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can use callback.

Comment: Do whatever action you want to perform in ajax success

Comment: Or [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function asynchrony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/)

Comment: I have brain explosion!!!

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax()` is async, you need to wait for it to finish.

```
var count;
$.ajax({
cache   :   false,
dataType:   'json',
type    :   "POST",
url     :   "count.php",
success  :   function(tdata){
    count = tdata;
    console.log(count); //this works

}               

})
.done(() => {
    // this code runs after ajax is resolved
    console.log(count);
});
```

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for other chaining methods

Comment: But I have big code! I can;t put it  .done(() => {});

Comment: Size of the code doesn't matter. Also, depending on your environment, you could try using async/await.